# Javascript regexp to remove duplicated spaces AND duplicated &nbsp; at the same time

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to normalize the extra white spaces from a string (normal spaces and the `&nbsp;` html entity) with a regexp or anything else that works.

I've been searching for a while but I haven't found anything to accomplish this, and I'm not familiar with REGEXP at all, so I wonder if a good soul could help me with this.

Example:

```
'foo&nbsp;&nbsp;bar'
'foo  bar'
```

to

```
'foo bar'
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;| )\1+/g, '$1');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX4mI3/1)

#### Explanation:

- `(&nbsp;| )` - match a space or `&nbsp;`, also groups it as matched group#1
- `\1+` - `\1` is back-reference to above captured group. Match 1 or more instances of same
- Replacement is `$1` is back-reference to above captured group

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:&nbsp;|\s)+/gi, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');

^ - Negation, 
\s - WhiteSpaces, 
\w - underscores, 
gi - global and case-insensitive
```